# Comparison Opeartor seemingly not working

Tags: php

I am trying to compare two values but when I do it does not appear to work.  I know what the values are so it should be reporting true.  Even worse, if I take either one of the variables out and put the number in it works.

```
$data = simplexml_load_file('xml/heroes/hero.xml')
    or die("Error: Cannot create object");
$hme = $data->hes->he->maxen;       
$hce = $data->hes->he->curen;
$hac = $data->hes->he->lastac;
echo $hce . ' should not be greater than ' . $hme;
if($hce > $hme){
echo 'should be working';
}
```

Outputs:

773 should not be greater than 20

Comment: You need to show the code where `$hce` and `$hme` are set.

Comment: What are `$hce` and `$hme`? Could they be strings?

Comment: Please show us the output of both `var_export($hce, true)` and `var_export($hme, true)`.

Comment: If `$hce = 773` and `$hme = 20`, this works correctly for me. Please post your whole code.

Comment: They are numbers pulled from an XML file and i've verified they have values.  Other comparisons are running on other parts of my site.  I'm starting to suspect the web server.

Comment: @Adrian That's good enough for me.  I think it's something funky with this web server appliance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your variable are like this

```
$hce = "773";
$hme = "20";
```

Before comparing them do intval

```
if(intval($hme)>intval($hce))
```

Answer (score 1):

Cast your strings to integers:

```
$hme = (int)$data->hes->he->maxen;       
$hce = (int)$data->hes->he->curen;
$hac = (int)$data->hes->he->lastac;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you took them as strings.I think you need to convert them to integer.

Simple function to do that:

```
int atoi(char *s)
{
int val = 0;
while (*s)
{
    val *= 10;
    val += (*s) - '0';
    s++;
}

return val;
}
```

Comment: This is a php question. Honest mistake, but please delete your answer before it gets flagged as "not an answer".